# STM32 - Modifying SYSCFG_UR2 register

Tags: stm32

I'm trying to modify the BOOT_ADD0 register field using STM32CubeProgrammer.

I've tried both:

- Writing a value using the Registers tab
- Writing to a memory address that the field occupies

But neither have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Modify it using option bytes, see BOOT_CM_ADD0 in FLASH_BOOT_PRG.

Option bytes are programmed under OB tab in the STM32CubeProgrammer.